# how can I search an FTP server for files that were modified after a specific date?

Tags: ftp

I'm currently using FileZilla, but its remote file search is limited to searching for filenames and filepaths. I'm looking for a way to search for all files that have been modified after a certain date. Is there an FTP client out there that has this capability?

Comment: You did not mention your OS.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu, but I have virtual machines installed running various flavors of Windows, so it doesn't really matter - if I can find a client for either Win or Linux that does this, I'll install wherever necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An oldie, no key though.

http://www.archive.org/details/tucows_288687_Super_Ftp_Search

This looks promising
http://www.wftpserver.com/ftprush.htm

Comment: Thanks! FTPRush does exactly what I need to do. It runs great on my virtual machine; I may try to run it under wine so I don't have to open vmware each time I need it.

Comment: Just tried in under wine and it's perfect. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 7):

I use [FileZilla](http://www.filezilla.de/download.htm) and it works perfectly!

Just select "Server" from the menu and then select "Filesearch on Server". Here, you can specify what ever you want to serch for.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That seems to be a relatively new feature, as it wasn't available 2 years ago when I first posted the question.